# Ruby mailto: adding subject and body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mailto

I am using the following with an embedded ruby tag to call the logged in users email address so it will populate the 'to' field when it opens the email client.

```
<h4 align="center">
  <%= link_to "Click to arrange swap",
    "mailto:#{@article.user.email}", class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary"%>
</h4>
```

But, I would like to add a subject (`article.artist`) to the email, and the URL of the page in the body of the email. 
Anyone any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can use also ActionView helper `mail_to` which has additional `html_options` attributes for subject, body etc.

```
<%= mail_to @article.user.email, "Click to arrange swap", subject: @article.artist, body: "Your content #{request.original_url}" %>
```

For more info, you can look up to this [link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/mail_to)

Comment: thank you so much,, this worked an absolute treat.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!